# Arrays in a Rock, Paper, Scissors game in bluej

Tags: java, arrays, bluej

I have two questions with my code. I am writing a program that simulates a game of Rock, Paper, Scissors played between two users. The winner is determined by the best of five computer generated rounds.

Three requirements:

1. You must write a loop to run the five rounds of the game, assigning the values into two arrays, allowing no ties.
2. You must write a loop to determine the number of wins for each player.
3. You must write a loop to print the values in each array (mapped to words).

I need help with the "allowing no ties" in the first requirement and mapping words to the values in the array to print in the third requirement.

So, I need these arrays:

Player 1    1 0 1 2 2

Player 2    2 1 0 1 0

to look like this:

Player 1    Player 2

paper         scissors

rock          paper

paper         rock

scissors      paper

scissors      rock

Here is my first loop:

```
    for(index=0; index<5; index++){
        player1[index]=random.nextInt(3);
        player2[index]=random.nextInt(3);
```

Second loop:

```
    for(index=0; index<5; index++){
        if((player1[index]==0) && (player2[index]==2)){
            player1Win++;
        }else if((player1[index]==1) && (player2[index]==0)){
            player1Win++;
        }else if((player1[index]==2) && (player2[index]==1)){
            player1Win++;
        }else{
            player2Win++;
        }
    }
```

Third loop:

```
    for(index=0; index<5; index++){
        System.out.print("\t\t " + player1[index] + "");
        System.out.println("\t  " + player2[index] + "");
    }
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

`player1[index]=random.nextInt(3);` is populating you arrays with integers.

`if((player1[index]=='0') && (player2[index]=='2')){` is comparing yours arrays as if they contain characters.

Try `if((player1[index]==0) && (player2[index]==2)){` etc (just remove the single quotes).

Answer (score 0):

For third question, have array of String like:

```
String [] names = new String[3];
names[0] = "Rock";
names[1] = "Paper";
names[2] = "Scissor";
```

Then map integer value [0,2] to String array like:

```
for(index = 0; index < 5; index++){
    System.out.println("\t\t" + names[player1[index]] + "\t" + names[player2[index]]);
}
```

For first question, just remove single quotes, you need to compare value in array to integer type, but you are comparing integer with character type, you wont get compile time error, but logically incorrect.

Comment: For first question, just remove single quotes, you need to compare value in array to integer type, but you are comparing integer with character type, you wont get compile time error, but logically incorrect.

Comment: Thank you very much for the help! On the first question, after I remove the single quotes, how do I prevent it from allowing ties? Is there a way to prevent ties during the first loop when the numbers are being randomly assigned, so if Player 1 gets a 0, Player 2 must get either a 1 or a 2?

Comment: Yes you could do that, get random number for first player. Then get random number for second player while both numbers are equal.

Answer (score 0):

```
        for(int j = 0; j <5; j++){
        if(player1[j] > player2[j]){// checks to see if player 1 has the upper hand
            play1++;// if so bam hers a point for the win
        }
        else if(player1[j] < player2[j]){ //if player 2 has the upper hand bam gets a point
            play2++;
        }
        if(player1[j] == player2[j]){ // meh if they are tied.. do it again!
            while(player1[j] == player2[j]){ // this is where you are having trouble
                //use this a psudo code to get an idea of how to steer your problematic thinking
                player1[j] = ran.nextInt(3);
                player2[j] = ran.nextInt(3);
            }
```

if you don't want the two values to be the same just over-write the current values to get new numbers until they are not equivalent